# Remove check out phase for woocommerce installation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a website for a wedding event.

There is a list of gifts guests can buy directly on the website (each is a small part of a honeymoon trip with a different price). You can pickup one or combine multiple items to reach the total amount you want to get.
When you have created your cart as you want I want to display the cart page with all the items to eventually update/remove items or quantities. At the bottom I just want to show a message that notifies the guest that he can do a bank transfer for the amount of his cart to "buy" the gift (the real gift are money).

What I want to remove is the checkout phase with addresses indication and the payment methods. This is not relevant. Also it is not relevant to reduce any quantity for the items bought. They can remain on the website and can be chosen again.

What is the easiest part to remove the checkout phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce adds the checkout button on this filter `add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );`
remove that action and you will no longer have a checkout button.  To add your own content at the bottom of the cart you could use that action or more appropriately, use the `woocommerce_after_cart` action.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'your_custom_function', 20);

function your_custom_function() {
    //echo message here
}
```